# How to implode a 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 2-d array as shown below :-

```
$variables = array(
           "firstname" => "Sachin",
           "lastname" => "Tendulkar",
           "course" => array(
                         0 => "PHP",
                         1 => "HTML",
                         2 => "CSS",
                         3 => "Javascript"
                 )
          );
```

I want to implode the "$variables" array and get only the list of values present in "course" in a variable separated by comma. Is it possible using array_column() ? Something like this is not working :-

```
$string = implode("," , array_column($variables,'course');
echo $string; //gives no output
var_dump($string); //gives string '' (length=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

No just directly access them instead:

```
$variables = array(
    "firstname" => "Sachin",
    "lastname" => "Tendulkar",
    "course" => array(
         0 => "PHP",
         1 => "HTML",
         2 => "CSS",
         3 => "Javascript"
     )
);

$courses = implode(', ', $variables['course']); // point it directly on the desired array
echo $courses; // PHP, HTML, CSS, Javascript
```

Comment: It throws this :- Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp\www\PhpSample\index.php. But works, I wanted it without this warning.

Comment: @sachintendulkar are you sure the example array you provided are exact as the one we are using?

Comment: Yes, it is the same array

Comment: @sachintendulkar are you really really sure? seems fine here http://codepad.viper-7.com/675Eld

Comment: Hmm, its strange,it works there, but not for me

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = implode(',', $variables['course']);
```

Comment: It throws this :- Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp\www\PhpSample\index.php. But works, I wanted it without this warning.

Comment: Make sure this is the only implode and you don't have leftovers from your previous example. For provided array this is correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply implode it by pointing it to the array in which you want to implode. Here is how your code should look like

```
$variables = array(
           "firstname" => "Sachin",
           "lastname" => "Tendulkar",
           "course" => array(
                         0 => "PHP",
                         1 => "HTML",
                         2 => "CSS",
                         3 => "Javascript"
                 )
          );


$string = implode(',', $variables['course']);

echo $string; //gives output
var_dump($string); //gives string
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: It throws this :- Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp\www\PhpSample\index.php. But works, I wanted it without this warning.

Comment: First of all tell me that are you using the same array because this code is working fine here http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php. Please test on this site, there might be a problem with your php version